# How do I see which user is locking a file using command prompt net file?

Tags: windows, command-line

I've searched around and I found that net file can be used in order to find out which user is locking a file. Notice I don't want to force close the file just yet

am I in the right path?

Answer (score 0):

#### Am I on the right path?

Yes.

`net file` without any further options will:

> list the open files on a server. **The listing includes** the
>   identification number assigned to an open file, the pathname of the file,
>   **the username**, and the number of locks on the file.

---

#### net file /help

```
The syntax of this command is:

NET FILE
[id [/CLOSE]]

NET FILE closes a shared file and removes file locks. When used without
options, it lists the open files on a server. The listing includes the
identification number assigned to an open file, the pathname of the file,
the username, and the number of locks on the file.

This command works only on computers running the Server service.

id      Is the identification number of the file.
/CLOSE  Closes an open file and removes file locks. Type this command
        from the server where the file is shared.
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [net](http://ss64.com/nt/net.html)  - The NET Command is used to manage network resources.